# How to import a external function in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a newbie in javascript and vue.js and I'm facing somme issue when trying to add a new function in an existing programme.

I have put my new function (with others) in a separate file:

```
export const MyFunctions = {
MyFunction: function(param) {
    // Doing stuff
}
}
```

Then I import the file in the component file and calling my function :

```
<script>
    import {MyFunctions} from "@/components/MyFunctions.js";
    export default {
        name:"Miniature",
        computed: {
            useMyFunction() {
                MyFunction("Please do some stuff !");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When the component is used, I get an error message

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "MyFunction" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

I've read a lot of documentation and fail to understand why it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this ??

Comment: you're importing `MyFunctions`, but your error message says `changeFavicon`

Comment: update code with MyFunctions.MyFunction("Please do some stuff !");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're exporting an object then in order to use the `MyFunction` you need to access to that function using dot notation, like this: `MyFunctions.MyFunction("Please do some stuff !")`

I made a working example for this use-case: https://codesandbox.io/s/62l1j19rvw

---

**MyFunctions.js**

```
export const MyFunctions = {
  MyFunction: function(param) {
    alert(param);
  }
};
```

---

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
   {{msg}}
   <button @click="handleClick">Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {MyFunctions} from "../MyFunctions.js";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App"
    };
  },
  methods:{
    handleClick: function(){
      MyFunctions.MyFunction("Please do some stuff !");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Just stumbled on this answer and whilst it works, I do get some errors I do not know what to do with - 
-Property or method "handleClick" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
and
-Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

Answer (score 5):

You can just import your javascript files into `.vue` files as long as they are inside `<script>` tags. Since **Vue.js** is after all javascript, the first part where you should look at while debugging is if you have some kind of mistake in your syntax. From what I see, there is some confusion with the `import` and `export` statements, which could be quite complex at first!

Check [MDN's Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) specially under [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports):

> In the module, we could use the following

```js
// module "my-module.js"
function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;
var graph = { /* nice big object */ }
export { cube, foo, graph };
```

> This way, in another script, we could have:

```js
import { cube, foo, graph } from 'my-module';
// Use your functions wisely
```

Answer (score 3):

what you export is an object, and what you use is a field/method inside this object, so you need to use your function this way:

```
MyFunctions.MyFunction("Please do some stuff !");
```